how is Answer document related to tags in the Question document in Elasticsearch documentation example
I am reading Elasticsearch documentation 8.15. Parent 1 has tags array.
PUT child_example/_doc/1
{
  "join": {
    "name": "question"
  },
  "body": "<p>I have Windows 2003 server and i bought a new Windows 2008 server...",
  "title": "Whats the best way to file transfer my site from server to a newer one?",
  "tags": [
    "windows-server-2003",
    "windows-server-2008",
    "file-transfer"
  ]
}

Here is one child.
PUT child_example/_doc/2?routing=1
{
  "join": {
    "name": "answer",
    "parent": "1"
  },
  "owner": {
    "location": "Norfolk, United Kingdom",
    "display_name": "Sam",
    "id": 48
  },
  "body": "<p>Unfortunately you're pretty much limited to FTP...",
  "creation_date": "2009-05-04T13:45:37.030"
}

This is the query to returns the top question tags and per tag the top answer owners.
POST child_example/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "top-tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "to-answers": {
          "children": {
            "type" : "answer" 
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top-names": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "owner.display_name.keyword",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

But how is Answer document related to tags in the Question document?

The question 1 has three tags:
"windows-server-2003",
"windows-server-2008",
"file-transfer"

and doc 2 ("display_name": "Sam"), doc 3 ("display_name": "Troll") belong to question 1, pay attention to
"join": {
    "name": "answer",
    "parent": "1"
}

which means question 1 has two answers, so each tag has two owner, it's like group by tag, owner in mysql.
